# Facing issue when combining 3 yii2 queries together

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have 3 queries in my yii2 project that are working perfectly as individual queries.So i need to combine these 3 queries

```
$variant_ids1=VariantProducts::find()
        ->select(['variant_id1'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->groupBy('variant_id1');
$variant_ids2=VariantProducts::find()
        ->select(['variant_id2'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->groupBy('variant_id2');
$variant_ids3=VariantProducts::find()
        ->select(['variant_id3'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->groupBy('variant_id3');
```

These are my 3 queries. For combining them I used union() like below

```
$variant_ids1->union($variant_ids2);
$variant_ids1->union($variant_ids3);
```

But this is working fine in the local server(Windows XAMPP), And not working when deployed to my Centos server. In local, I am getting the correct output the same as I want.

What will be the issue?. And are there any other ways to combine them?

When I deployed to the server I am getting MySQL error like [see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNcj1.png)

Answer (score 0):

could be you are using two different version of mysql  one <5.7 (localhost) and one >= 5.7 (server)

do the fact you have an improper use of group by () allowed in mysql<5.7 but not allowed, by deafult, in mysql >= 5.7) this could produce an error

You should not use group by without aggregation function ,  for obtain disticnt row without aggreation function usw ->distinct()

```
$variant_ids1=VariantProducts::find()
        ->select(['variant_id1'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->distinct();
$variant_ids2=VariantProducts::find()
        ->select(['variant_id2'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->distinct();
$variant_ids3=VariantProducts::find()
        ->select(['variant_id3'])
                ->where(['shop_id'=>$searchModel->user_id])
                ->orWhere(['category_id'=>$searchModel->category_id,'position'=>null])
                ->distinct();
```

another issue could be related  to the IN clause . the length of the in content is limited by  max_allowed_packet param  so you should check for this param both of your db and eval if these value are compatible with you union result

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet